# Lookup Searches Only the name field is searched

Tags: lookup, mobile, search

Is there any work around for "Lookup Searches - Only the name field is searched." when using the Mobile App?

The information is taken from here: [Search: What’s Different or Not Available in the Salesforce App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_mobile_sf1_search.htm&type=5)

It seems really limited to only offer the name field for searching via lookups in the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually came across this requirement myself. Whilst not an ideal solution we were actually able to change the Name field to contain a unique description of each record rather than a meaningless combination of letters/numbers that acted as an ID.

This was much more searchable and had the added bonus of reducing the requirement to use formula fields to display appropriate lookup record information as a "normal" lookup field only shows the name value.